# Angular2 test toPromise().then

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Do you have any idea how can I create good test for code like this:

```
  login(login, password) {
    console.log('login is called');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let data = JSON.stringify({
      username: login,
      password: password
    });

    var $self = this;

    this.http.post(
      'http://localhost:8080/auth',
      data,
      { headers }
    ).toPromise()
      .then(function(response){
        console.log('Then is resolved');
        $self.setUserId(result.id);
        $self.router.navigate([ '' ]);
      });
  }
```

What I want to check:

- `getUserId()` before i call `login(login, password)` should be undefined
- when I call `login(login, password)` i should see in console that then is called (in console should be called `console.log('then is called')`)
- `getUserId()` after i call `login(login, password)` should return numeric value, because result in then should be an object `{id: XXX, token: YYY}`

I prepare spec.ts but I never see the `then` in `login` result :

```
 beforeEach( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        UserService
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([UserService, XHRBackend, Router], (_userService, mockBackend) => {
    userService = _userService;
  }));

  describe('Login', () => {
    it('user is not login', () => {
        expect(userService.loggedIn).toBe(false);
    });

    it('login with good data',async(() => {
      let login = "admin";
      let pass = "admin";

      expect(userService.getUserId()).not.toBeDefined();

      let res = {
        token: 'testtest',
        id: '1'
      };

      userService.login(login, pass);

      userService.whenStable().then(() => {
        userService.login(login, pass);
        expect(userService.getUserId()).toBeDefined();
      });
    }));
  });
```

Comment: Ideally you would have better SoC (separation of concerns) and have an authentication service that makes the call and returns the result as a Promise (or observable). The component would then do any routing or setting of state. You then test the component code with a fake service and test the service with the [MockBackend](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend).

Comment: Thanks Igor, as I understand your suggestion - it's too spaghetti code to make test as I have in mind, and I should rebuild code to do it. It was my first idea, but I was very curious how can I manage with it.

Thanks for help!